# How Can I Specify a Directory without Using the Full Directory Name? - Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I don't want to specify the full directory of a folder or object within my program. I do not want to do this because if a user decides to change the installation folder, it will not function properly. I've seen in HTML you can do something like: ./folder/directory/name and it would work perfectly fine. Is there a way to do something like that within Python?

Comment: Yes, do exactly what you describe. "." is interpreted as "the current working directory" by functions that care about paths.

Comment: I did not realize that it wasn't only HTML that that worked. +1 for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded

You may find it helpful to apply os.path.abspath() to '.' or `__file__`.